# Git delete untracked directory

Tags: git

I have an untracked directory full of files I want to delete.  When I run `git clean -n` or `git clean -f` it does not delete the untracked directory of files.  How do I delete an untracked directory of files?

Answer (score -2):

To delete an untracked directory of files, run `git clean -f -d`